# Problem with an Already Asked Question

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

This question already exists on this site -
[Show that if $x,x^{'}\in C$ then $C_x=C_{x^{'}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101152/show-that-if-x-x-in-c-then-c-x-c-x).

> Let $C$ be a closed convex set in $\Bbb R^2$.
>
> Define $C_x=\{y:x+ty\in C\forall t \geq 0\}$.
>
> Show that if $x,x^{'}\in C$ then $C_x=C_{x^{'}}$.

Can anyone please help me with this? My initial idea was to show that $C_x$ are the connected components, but I am not sure if I am on the right path to solving this problem. A rigorous solution is what I am trying to get at. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't see a link with topology.

Comment: I thought that topology was needed to solve this, but it seems one can solve without using it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $x+ty\in C$ for every $t\geq0$, let $x'\in C$ and let $t_0>0$.

It is our aim (and that is enough) to prove that $x'+t_0y\in C$, and since $C$ is closed we can do that by finding a sequence in $C$ that converges to $x'+t_0y\in C$.

Since $C$ is convex for every $t>0$ the triangle with vertices $x,x',x+ty$ will be a subset of $C$.

Then $\lambda(x+ty)+(1-\lambda)x'\in C$ for every $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Now let $t_n\to\infty$ and let $t_0=\lambda_n t_n$.

Then consequently $\lambda_n\to0$ so that: $$\lambda_n(x+t_ny)+(1-\lambda_n)x'=x'+t_0y+\lambda_n(x-x')\to x'+t_0y$$

Comment: This could be animated as a "Proof Without Words."